# the code is about making user photo upload

Tags: php

i have this error when i am trying to upload a picture to the database and this is the code :

```
<?php   

include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $random_name = rand();
             
    if(empty($file)){
        echo "Please choose a picture <br/><br/>";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '../profilepics/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO userphoto VALUES ('$random_name.jpg')");
                 
        header('location: timeline.php');
    }
}                   
?>
```

and then its says :

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Echo\php\userphotoupload.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Echo\php\userphotoupload.php on line 7

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Does your form have `enctype` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Usually indicates missing or mislabeled form `<input type=file name=file>` field. See also [Notice: Undefined index: file for $_FILES](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Notice:+Undefined+index:+file+for+%24_FILES+form)

Comment: The key to the $_FILES array - `'file'` has to match the name attribute used on the HTML `<input type="file" name="file"...>` does yours? If all you have used is a `<input type="file" id="file"...>` that will not do

Comment: Also note just randomly selecting a number for the filenames isnt the best. The script could pick the same number twice. Why not use auto-incrementing column and pull the last inserted id (for the move, e.g. insert first then move)?

Comment: Where are you `$_POST` values?